# Sending Intent from Listview onItemClickListener error

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Just a quick question, I'm guessing I've missed something really easy and obvious. The following code is called when a listview item is accessed, and it passes the id to the next activity. I'm getting a runtime error, log cat is showing me this

```
error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tim.apps.list/com.tim.apps.list.Challengeview}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
```

Heres the code for my first activity:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            String index = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position); 
            //Intent myIntent = new Intent(ChallengesList.this, Challengeview.class);
            //ChallengesList.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Challengeview.class);
            i.putExtra(index, position);
            startActivity(i);
      }
   });
```

And in my second activity..

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = extras.getString("index");

//Convert the passed id to a integer
int intvalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Thanks heaps for any help you guys can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong on both end (Sending/receiving). you can use this as i.putExtra(String,String).In your case if u want to receive String then u need to send string only as i am adding "" to position.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Challengeview.class);
        i.putExtra("index", ""+position);
        startActivity(i);
```

and at receiving end u have to do like this.

```
String value =getIntent().getStringExtras("index");
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!! I've only been coding with android/java for a few weeks, so your help is very appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: @TimJ you can accept answer for appreciate me and others to know the useful answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

you are giving the item data as the **key** and you are retrieving the data with key as `"index"`

Change

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Challengeview.class);
i.putExtra(index, position);
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Challengeview.class);
i.putExtra("index", position);
```

While Retrieving , give the same key `"index"` to get the data..

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("index");
    // Convert the passed id to a integer
    int intvalue = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```

Comment: I think Challangeview is the second activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using different keys in each activity:

```
String index = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

will return a string representation of your item.
So what you are putting into your intent is: ItemString -> position
What you want in your intent is: "index" -> position